# Set of planes to create a geometric plane

Tags: vector-spaces

How do I come up with a set of planes that will create a geometric shape? The shape can contain up to 40 sides. Is there any general formula/equation to solve this kind of question?

Comment: Unclear. Do you mean this as an algorithmic problem? The algorithm will need input data "a geometric shape" given to it in some form, and the process will depend on that form.

Comment: No, the question will be like "Determine a set of planes that will create a pyramid."